# audio decoding memory leak ffmpeg

Tags: c++, audio, memory-leaks, ffmpeg, decoding

I am using ffmpeg library to develop app for audio decoding.

I am using `avcodec_decode_audio4()` function but it has pretty significant memory leak. I tried with `av_frame_unref()` but leak remained.

Afterwards, I switched to newest version of library where  `avcodec_decode_audio4()` is deprecated and few other stuff as well.

Can anyone point me to example how to decode frame without using `avcodec_decode_audio4()` or how to get rid of memory leak.

Thanks,

EDIT:

I found way. Looking on given examples on ffmpeg documentation with `avcodec_decode_audio4()` I made few changes.

```
AVCodec *codec;
AVCodecContext *c = NULL;

c = avcodec_alloc_context3(NULL);

for (int i = 0; i < m_ctx->nb_streams; ++i) {
    AVCodecParameters* tc = m_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar;
    if (tc->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        if(avcodec_parameters_to_context(c,tc) < 0){
            return false;
        }
        break;
    }
}

if(avcodec_open2(c, codec, 0) < 0)
    return false;

AVPacket avpkt;
AVFrame *decoded_frame = NULL;  

decoded_frame = av_frame_alloc();
av_init_packet(&avpkt);

while(av_read_frame(m_ctx, &avpkt) >= 0){

    if(!getFrame(&avpkt, c, decoded_frame)){
        av_frame_unref(decoded_frame);
        av_packet_unref(&avpkt);
        continue;
    }

    // your code here

    av_frame_unref(decoded_frame);
    av_packet_unref(&avpkt);
}
```

GetFrame method:

```
bool getFrame(AVPacket* avpkt, AVCodecContext* c, AVFrame* frame){
    if(avcodec_send_packet(c,avpkt) < 0){
        return false;
    }

    if(avcodec_receive_frame(c, frame) < 0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And m_ctx is class field variable AVFormatContext* which is initialized earlier.

Anyway problem is with AVPacket buffers which are not freed after packet is used which is solved with `av_packet_unref`

Comment: It's impossible to decide what type of memory leaks you have without the actual decoding code...

Comment: I found what is leaking, in meanwhile I switched to newer version of ffmpeg library. Problem was in AVPacket which wasnt releasing its buffers after being used. I am writing EDIT: right now :)

Comment: I was convinced `av_read_frame` was using same logic `avcodec_receive_frame`, releasing the pooled packet before doing anything else, but it is not. Memory leak found, thanks